# Simple architecture design program

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for a very simple architecture design program. If it were open source, that would be awesome! I just want to create a kind of map of rooms, and add only borders of furniture items.

Comment: Sketchup runs great in WINE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made basic architectural drawings (for work) using CAD software such as [Free CAD](http://www.freecadweb.org/)

You can certainly draw floor plans and so on in this type of software, but it takes a bit of practice to use fluently - I don't know if it's the simplest. But it is great for scaling and drawing with measurements.

You can get Free CAD from Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install freecad
```

It's open source and you can contribute to development - here's the [GitHub page](https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD)

Answer (score 2):

There's also [Sweethome 3D](http://www.sweethome3d.com/index.jsp). It's more of an interior decorators type of package, with all sorts of bells and whistles, but seems fairly intuitive in terms of user interface. You can probably leave diagrams at a more basic level.

It's available in the universe section of the Ubuntu repositories, so is likely to be available through software centre, or can be installed with the terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install sweethome3d
```